# ¿Cómo enviar al Clipboard de Windows varios Ficheros?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows, filesystem

Quisiera saber si desde una app Windows Forms con C# podría enviar al Clipbaord varios ficheros para ser pegados posteriormente. Es decir que puedo posicionarme en cualquier carpeta de mi PC y cuando de Pegar se me deben pegar estos archivos. Esto es solo una parte del problema pero bueno es mejor ir desmenuzandolo por partes. He trabajado con el Clipboard pero poniendo texto o imágenes. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase [ClipBoard Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) para ello de la siguiente manera:

```
StringCollection paths = new StringCollection();
paths.Add("c:\\temp\\test.txt");
paths.Add("c:\\temp\\test2.txt");
Clipboard.Clear(); //Para borrar lo que esté en el Clipboard
Clipboard.SetFileDropList(paths);
```

Este código te pone en el Clipboard los archivos `test.txt` y `test2.txt`, y sólo tendrás que entrar en la carpeta en cuestión y pegarlo normal.

Comment: Me funcionó a la perfección. Gracias. Como antes habia aclarado esto es un proyecto algo más grande y esta era la primera piedra que me encontraba en el camino. Ahora si quisiera poner el contenido del Clipboard en una carpeta sin la interacción del usuario ¿cómo sería?. Se que puedo abrir la carpeta donde quiero copiar estos ficheros y mandarle una combinación de teclas pero quiero que todo quede oculto a la vista del usuario. Evitar abrir la ventana. Tambien podría copiar los ficheros internamente pero deseo que se lance el copiador de windows o el que tenga predeterminado en la PC.

Comment: Que es lo que te llevo a sólo usar el Clipboard para copiar archivos? Creo que te estas complicando un poco al usar eso, te recomiendo que mires como funciona la clase [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) para poder copiar los archivos a la carpeta destino y cambiar los atributos.

Comment: El problema de usar la clase File es que el proceso de copiado se realiza en background y por mi aplicación y yo necesito que se realice con el copiador que tenga por defecto el sistema operativo (Windows) por gustos del cliente. Al tener la lista de ficheros en el Clipboard solo tendría que mandar un sato Ctrl+P a la ventana donde quiero copiarlos. Bueno esa era la idea